Next.js app router project not auto updating on localhost when I save
I'm trying my first project as app router Next.js instead of page router, in app router when I save in vs code it doesn't update the localhost, I have to terminate the server and initiate it again "npm run dev", while in page router it auto updates without terminating the server.
tried to terminate server several times and initiate it again but nothing happens.

try to delete node_module and reinstall
